# Better way to turn object with named booleans into array with their uppercase keys?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express-router

I'm trying to convert the methods part of an Express Router into a one-dimensional array of uppercase string words, so this:

```
layer.route.methods: { get: true, post: true }
```

into:

```
methods: ["GET", "POST"]
```

This is what I came up with, but isn't there a more subtle way?

```
const methods = [];
!layer.route.methods.get || methods.push('GET');
!layer.route.methods.post || methods.push('POST');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be achieved with a combination of `filter` (to get only the methods with `true`) and `map` (to capitalize).

```js
const methods = { get: true, post: true };

const result = Object.keys(methods).filter(method => methods[method]).map(method => method.toUpperCase());

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Exactly the subtlety I was hoping for. And a oneliner, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turn down object to an array by using `Object.keys(object)` and then use loop either for or map to iterate and check if item exist in that converted array convert then to uppercase using `item.toUpperCase()`

Answer (score -1):

One of the ways is to use reducer, to filter and modify values in one iteration.

```js
const inputObject = { get: true, post: true };

const methods = Object.entries(inputObject).reduce(
  (accumulator, [key, value]) => {
    if (value) accumulator.push(key.toUpperCase());
    return accumulator;
  },
  []
);

console.log(methods);
```

Comment: This is a good answer. I'd consider changing the `reduce` to avoid mutation:
`.reduce((acc, [key, value]) => value ? [...acc, key.toUpperCase()] : acc, [])`.

Comment: I haven't chosen this as the answer, but nevertheless it's a good way , thank you